# BASH SHELL query

Tags: bash, shell, if-statement, scripting

I am having the following if condition:

```
[[ -f ${OFSR_CFG}/LoadVariables_SMITH.bash && "${SMITH_SCRIPT}" = "MAIN" && !(-f ${OFSR_CFG}/LoadVariables_MI.bash)]]
```

but i want to introduce one more script value `"${SMITH_SCRIPT}" = "RELOAD"`. basically it should be either `MAIN` or `RELOAD`.

I tried the following conditions:

```
[[ -f ${OFSR_CFG}/LoadVariables_SMITH.bash && [["${SMITH_SCRIPT}" = "MAIN" **|| "${SMITH_SCRIPT}" = "RELOAD"**]]  && !(-f ${OFSR_CFG}/LoadVariables_MI.bash)]]
```

but it is not identify `RELOAD` script. The condition is not satisfying.

Please help.

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can't nest `[[` like that (you want grouping `( ... )` instead).

You need space between the `[[` and the first argument and between the last argument and `]]`.

Try:

```
[[ -f ${OFSR_CFG}/LoadVariables_SMITH.bash && ("${SMITH_SCRIPT}" = "MAIN" || "${SMITH_SCRIPT}" = "RELOAD")  && !(-f ${OFSR_CFG}/LoadVariables_MI.bash) ]]
```

Comment: @user1468031 Define "not working"? Do you get an error? What happens? For that matter you didn't tell us how your original was not working exactly.